# Using featuretool, how to use dfs primitives individually?

Tags: featuretools

Could you help me? when I used feturestools, I use iris dataset, it has 4 features as follows: f1, f2, f3, f4, when I use ft.dfsI have 3 tow questions. 
1. I found that feature_matrix has too much features. the 'divide_by_feature' and 'modulo_numeric' didn't act on original features individually. It firstly act divide_by_feature' then got 4 features newly, and then act 'modulo_numeric' on original features and new features.
I hope the two primitives can act on original features individually. How should I do?
2. I use transform primitives like trans_primitives = ['subtract_numeric_scalar', 'modulo_numeric']. I found that subtract_numeric_scalar can pass an value, however, I don't know how to pass?
3. I wonder how to use all transform primitives? default, trans_primitives=None, by now, I can solve it like this: trans_primitives = ['is_null','diff',...], however, I think that it's trouble.

could you give me some advice? Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JVZy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can use `max_depth` to control the complexity of the features. When `max_depth=1`, the primitives will use only original features.

   ```py
   features = ft.dfs(
       entityset=es,
       target_entity='data',
       trans_primitives=['divide_by_feature', 'modulo_numeric'],
       features_only=True,
       max_depth=1,
   )
   ```

   ```
   [<Feature: f1>,
   <Feature: f2>,
   <Feature: f3>,
   <Feature: f4>,
   <Feature: 1 / f3>,
   <Feature: 1 / f1>,
   <Feature: 1 / f2>,
   <Feature: 1 / f4>,
   <Feature: f1 % f2>,
   <Feature: f4 % f3>,
   <Feature: f4 % f2>,
   <Feature: f1 % f3>,
   <Feature: f2 % f4>,
   <Feature: f4 % f1>,
   <Feature: f3 % f2>,
   <Feature: f3 % f1>,
   <Feature: f2 % f1>,
   <Feature: f3 % f4>,
   <Feature: f2 % f3>,
   <Feature: f1 % f4>]
   ```
2. You can create an instance of a primitive with the parameters. This is how you can pass a value to `subtract_numeric_scalar`.

   ```py
   from featuretools.primitives import SubtractNumericScalar

   ft.dfs(
       ...
       trans_primitives=[SubtractNumericScalar(value=2)]
   )
   ```
3. You can use all transform primitives by extracting the names from the primitive list.

   ```py
   primitives = ft.list_primitives()
   primitives = primitives.groupby('type')
   transforms = primitives.get_group('transform')
   transforms = transforms.name.values.tolist()
   ```

   ```
   ['less_than_scalar',
   'divide_numeric',
   'latitude',
   'add_numeric',
   'week',
   'greater_than_equal_to_scalar',
   'and',
   'multiply_numeric_scalar',
   'not',
   'second',
   'greater_than_scalar',
   'modulo_numeric_scalar',
   'scalar_subtract_numeric_feature',
   'diff',
   'day',
   'cum_min',
   'divide_by_feature',
   'less_than_equal_to',
   'time_since',
   'time_since_previous',
   'cum_count',
   'year',
   'is_null',
   'num_characters',
   'equal_scalar',
   'is_weekend',
   'less_than_equal_to_scalar',
   'longitude',
   'add_numeric_scalar',
   'month',
   'less_than',
   'or',
   'multiply_boolean',
   'percentile',
   'minute',
   'not_equal_scalar',
   'greater_than_equal_to',
   'modulo_by_feature',
   'multiply_numeric',
   'negate',
   'hour',
   'cum_max',
   'greater_than',
   'modulo_numeric',
   'subtract_numeric_scalar',
   'isin',
   'cum_mean',
   'divide_numeric_scalar',
   'num_words',
   'absolute',
   'cum_sum',
   'not_equal',
   'weekday',
   'equal',
   'haversine',
   'subtract_numeric']
   ```

   Let me know if this helps.